# How to stop substraction if that is not possible?

Tags: java, if-statement

Im makeing selling players app for my project, and now i have setted money and i can buy player if i have enough money, but if dont have enough money how to stop substraction?

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(cijenaIgraca.getText());
int b = Integer.parseInt(kapital.getText());
String c = String.valueOf(b-a);
this.kapital.setText(c);
if(b < a) {
    this.porukica.setText("Usli ste u minus, imacete troskove!");
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i am new and i made mistake :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re already using an `if` statement. That’s the key to what you want.

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(cijenaIgraca.getText());
int b = Integer.parseInt(kapital.getText());
if(b < a) {
    this.porukica.setText("Usli ste u minus, imacete troskove!");
} else {
    String c = String.valueOf(b-a);
    this.kapital.setText(c);
}
```

Just add an `else` part as shown so the subtraction will only happen in that case.